Could not create task ':app:processDebugResources'
I build an apk on sketchwere, Now I am trying to open / import the project in android studio.
but Faced many issue and fixed them by watching video , but now this error came
biuld.gradle
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

app/build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gamestopupbd.a"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
}


I am beginner, If ny one can convert my sketchwere project to android studio or solve this problem

Please paste the entire error into the question, not just the first line.  There is likely relevant information in it.
